# See data before ssl encryption?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, browser

Is there a way that I can see the data which chrome, or any other browser that can do that, send before its encrypting it (on SSL site)?

For example, if I surf to https://facebook.com and do a login, I want to see the HTTP request before it will be encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, open the Developer Tools, choose the Network tab, click the record button (the circle), and then browse. You'll be able to see the individual requests, their headers (or, if you prefer, raw source), response headers, response body, cookies, timing information, etc.

Since this data is generated by the browser itself, it's unencrypted.